# getting selected data from a vector then storing as a variable

Tags: c++, variables, vector, integer, double

Ive currently stored all my data into a vector as variables. im trying to get selected data from that vector, storing then as variables so i can then do calculations, save the answers as a variable to then store back in my original vector?

The data file is in the format below;

```
    a     b       c        d      e
    1    7.3     0.8      14    74.6     
    2    6.5     0.1      13     3.3     
    3   10.8     1.4      12    75.8     
    4   13.2     3.5       6    32.4
```

my code is as below so far;

```
struct Weather
{
  int a_data;
  double b_data;
  double c_data;
  int d_data;
  double e_data;
  double ans_data;
};



int main () 
{
  using std::vector;
  using std::string;
  using std::getline;
  using std::cout;

  vector<Weather> data_weather;
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("weatherdata.txt");

  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    int count = 0;
    while (getline(myfile, line)) 
    {
      if (count > 6) 
      {
            int a, d; 
            double b, c, e;
            std::istringstream buffer(line); 
            std::string sun_as_string;
            if (buffer >> a >> b >> c >> d >>e_as_string) 
            {
                if (e_as_string == "---")
                {
                    e = 0.0;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::istringstream buffer2(e_as_string);
                    if (!(buffer2 >> e))
                    {
                        e = 0.0;
                    }
                }
                Weather objName = {a, b, c, d, e};
                data_weather.push_back(objName);  
            }
      }
      count++;
    }
    myfile.close();

    double temp_b, temp_c, temp_ans; //declaring my new variables
    for (auto it = data_weather.begin(); it != data_weather.end(); ++it)
    { 
        std::cout << it->b_data << " " << it->c_data << std::endl;

    }
 }

   }
   else 

   cout << "unable to open file";

   scat::pause("\nPress <ENTER> to end the program.");

   return 0;
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: how do i store selected data from my vector into a variable to the use, and put back into the vector?

Comment: for example if i wanted to do 10.8 + 1.4 / 4, then store the answer in temp_ans

Comment: Can you show the code for the Weather object?  The would be helpful to see the members.

Comment: @Glenn see above, ive edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Am missing something obvious or do you simply need to do this?

```
for (auto it = data_weather.begin(); it != data_weather.end(); ++it)
{ 
    it->ans_data = it->b_data * it->c_data;
}
```

Dereferencing an iterator gives you a reference to an existing object inside the vector. You don't really need temporary variables for this.

A nicer C++11 alternative is a range based for loop:

```
for (Weather& w : data_weather)
{
    w.ans_data = w.b_data * w.c_data;
}
```

Given a list of indices of lines you want to work with, you can do something like this:

```
Weather& w = data_weather[i]; // shortcut so you don't need to
                              // write data_waether[i] each time
w.ans_data = (w.b_data * w.c_data)/2;
```

where i is the index of the line your interested in. You might want to put this is some kind of a loop. I leave that as an exercise for you :)

Comment: would this not just multiply all b_data by c_data, as apposed to individual data from b and c? or would i multiply like you've shown then call selected answers when needed? if so how would i go about that

Comment: The loop goes through each `Weather` object inside the vector and multiplies each object's b_data and c_data and stores them in ans_data, yes. I was under impression that this is what you wanted, correct me if it's not.

Comment: yeah for example 10.8 * 1.4 /2   say i wanted to add up the answers for this equation for lines 3 & 4, ignoring 1&2, or any combo, is this easily achieved?

Comment: `Weather& w = data_weather[i]; w.ans_data = (w.b_data * w.c_data)/2;` where `i` is the index of the line you want. Do this for each line.

Comment: @ thanks is that likely to work on c++ vs 2010? could u apply that theory to youre first answer if thats ok?

Comment: @jaylad Of course it'll work, this is very basic stuff. I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks, im new to c++. now ive completed my vector is it relativly easy to write this vector to a new text file?

Answer (score 0):

I would structure this somewhat differently. I'd write the code for reading the data as an `operator>>` for the `Weather` structure:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Weather &w) { 
    std::string line;
    std::getline(is, line);
    std::istringstream buffer(line); 

    buffer >> w.a >> w.b >> w.c >> w.d;
    if (!buffer >> w.e) // conversion will fail for "---" or not-present
        w.e = 0.0;
    return is;
}
```

This can simplify reading the data:

```
std::ifstream myfile("Weather.txt");

std::string ign;
std::getline(myfile, ign);   // skip that pesky first line

// Now we can initialize the vector directly from the data in the file:
std::vector<Weather> weather_data((std::istream_iterator<Weather>(myfile)),
                                  std::istream_iterator<Weather>());
```

With a reasonably recent compiler, printing out the data can be simplified as well:

```
for (auto &w : weather_data)
    std::cout << w.b_data << " " << w.c_data << "\n";
```

If you want to do a calculation, and put a result back into the `ans` field of your structure, that's fairly easy also. For example, let's assume `b`, `c` and `d` are temperatures, and we want `ans` to contain the average of the three:

```
for (auto &w : weather_data)
     w.ans = (w.b_data + w.c_data + w.d_data)/3.0;
```

Comment: thanks, that is a different approach, i will have a look at that tonight. from that point would it be relatively easy to write my calculated values from the vector into a new text file?

Comment: @jaylad: yes: `for (auto w : weather_data) some_file << w.ans << "\n";`

Comment: would this create a text file, or would i need to do that before writing data to it?

Comment: @jaylad: You'd create the text file (with `std::ofstream("whatever.txt");`) first, then write to it with code like above.

Comment: appreciate that, going to try this approach later

Comment: so would it be (auto w : weather_data) whatever.txt << w.ans << "\n";

Comment: also would this work on c++2010, i don't have 2011 at the min

Comment: @jaylad: I *believe* 2010 has range-based `for`, but I can't remember for sure.